# Spring Boot mvn Project doesn't run after adding dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I developed simple functionalities in a small Spring Boot Project. Now I want to move these functionalities into an older existing project that I sadly did not develop by myself and did not follow the advices on how to build the pom by specifying a parent.
I am not that experienced in Spring Boot to be able to resolve the errors when I try to add new new dependencies into the old project.

The pom.xml of the newer working project:
To summarize I have the starter-parent and dependencies for data-jpa, web, mysql and lombok.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>removed</groupId>
    <artifactId>removed</artifactId>
    <version>removed</version>
    <name>removed</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The pom.xml of the older project looks like the following:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>removed</groupId>
    <artifactId>removed</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <name>removed</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>
        <mvn.compiler.version>3.5.1</mvn.compiler.version>
        <hibernate.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}${file.separator}lib</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mvn.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

The older projects runs fine as long as I dont touch the pom. Once I add for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error while trying to run the project:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:607) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at App.main(App.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
```

Do you have any tips or advice?

Comment: you are mixing 2.7.0 and 2.1.1 versions of spring boot dependencies. This is most likely causing the `NoClassDefFoundError` issue. Please use the same versions of spring boot dependencies.

Comment: Also why have you defined things like `file://${basedir}${file.separator}lib</url>` also why using milestone repositories of spring..furthermore things like `<version>RELEASE</version>` do not work and are deprecated for a long time...also having defined a dependency to junit-jupiter which will only work with maven-surefire-plugin with version 2.22.2 at minimum but you have defined `<version>2.21.0</version>`... ??

Comment: ApplicationStartup is in spring-core.jar, use 
1.mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose or
2.IDEA 'Show Dependencies'
to identify whether there are multiple versions of spring-core